# I don't understand why my Athena (Presto) SQL query doesn't work

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have both a specific question and a more general question... for context, I'm using Athena. Here's my specific question:

1) I'm trying to write a query where I calculate the DAUs for 2 successive months broken down by country (I eventually want the DAUs/MAUs broken down by country and day but thought I'd start simple...). My thinking on how to approach this was I'd need two queries, one for each month, that used a group by on country and applied the necessary filters. Finally, I'd be able to join on country to get 1 column that contained countries, and the following columns containing the two months of DAUS. Here's the query I rustled up:

```
 SELECT count(distinct uuid) m1, country
FROM user u1
WHERE month(date(dt)) = 12 
AND YEAR(date(dt)) = 2018

INNER JOIN (SELECT count(distinct uuid) m2, country
  FROM user
  WHERE month(date(dt)) = 11
        AND YEAR(date(dt)) = 2018 GROUP BY country
) t ON t.country = u1.country

GROUP BY country
```

What's the issue with this? Error: `mismatched input 'join' expecting {<eof>`

2) My more general question is, how should I think when constructing more complex queries? I've programmed for years yet I seem to always find myself getting stuck with complicated SQL queries and hitting error message after error message (which also seem almost uninterpretable).

Thanks for all advice :)

Comment: Your first question suggests that you don't understand the basic syntax of SQL.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  Any SQL you provide would be helpful.

Comment: Look at the SQL your sections/order of processing, they are not valid SQL.  Your join is not in correct place (must come before where and group by) and group by must come last

Comment: Before writing SQL query, probably the first thing you should do is learn how to write the correct syntax.  No dbms will be able to execute your query.

Comment: Regarding Q2: *I've programmed for years* this is probably the reason why you got problems with SQL :-) Switching to so-called *set-based thinking* means to forget a lot of the things you did before. Btw, it's not really easier to interpret error messages returned by programming languages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to join the result of two Selects:

```
SELECT t2.*, t.m2
FROM
 (   
   SELECT count(distinct uuid) m1, country
   FROM user u1
   WHERE month(date(dt)) = 12
     AND YEAR(date(dt)) = 2018
   GROUP BY country
 ) as t2
JOIN
 (
   SELECT count(distinct uuid) m2, country
   FROM user
   WHERE month(date(dt)) = 11
     AND YEAR(date(dt)) = 2018
   GROUP BY country
 ) as t
ON t.country = t2.country
```

But this will remove countries which don't have data for both months and then you have to switch to a FULL OUTER JOIN.

In your case it's much easier to use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT country
  ,count(distinct case when month(date(dt)) = 12 AND YEAR(date(dt)) = 2018 then uuid end) as m1
  ,count(distinct case when month(date(dt)) = 11 AND YEAR(date(dt)) = 2018 then uuid end) as m2
FROM user
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although the second way of doing it definitely makes more sense in this case, it was the first way I was looking for so I could conceptually understand how to structure the queries. Again, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The where and group by should be place after the the where join  clause

```
    SELECT count(distinct uuid) m1, country
    FROM user u1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT count(distinct uuid) m2, country
      FROM user
      WHERE month(date(dt)) = 11
            AND YEAR(date(dt)) = 2018 GROUP BY country
    ) t ON t.country = u1.country
    WHERE month(date(dt)) = 12 
    AND YEAR(date(dt)) = 2018
    GROUP BY country
```

Comment: That was actually typo - this still generates an error for me:

line 6:5: mismatched input 'join' expecting {<eof>, '.', '[', 'group', 'order', 'having', 'limit', 'at', 'or', 'and', 'union', 'except', 'intersect', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '||'} (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 1385cbc9-e45a-495f-93e6-cc037cda9eee)